# Script for Success of HTLC in the Lightning Network

Tags: lightning-network, script, hash-time-locked-contract

BOLT #3 [specifies](https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/03-transactions.md#htlc-timeout-and-htlc-success-transactions) that an HTLC success transaction (the second-stage transaction that spends an HTLC by providing the preimage) has the witness script `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig>  <payment_preimage>`.
[This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92087/can-someone-explain-how-an-htlc-is-redeemed) and the respective answers assume that the input script of the HTLC success transaction is `<remotehtlcsig> <payment_preimage>`. The answers explain in detail how the scripts are executed.

As [implementations seem](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/bitcoin/script.c#L805) to implement the script according to the specification, I wonder how the script is actually executed. How does the script execution work if there is the additional `localhtlcsig`? Is the `localhtlcsig` dropped from the stack at some point during the execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the present time the Script for a "received HTLC output", that is for an HTLC that is paying us materialized as an output in our own commitment transaction, is (comments mine):

```
# Is it the hash of the revocation public key that we are presented?
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(SHA256(revocationpubkey))> OP_EQUAL
OP_IF
    # If so, anyone that can provide a signature for it can spend this coin.
    OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ELSE
    # Otherwise, are we presented a 32-bytes long bytestring?
    <remote_htlcpubkey> OP_SWAP OP_SIZE 32 OP_EQUAL
    OP_IF
        # If so, we assume this is the payment hash preimage.
        # It must hash through ripemd160(sha256()) to the ripemd160() of the payment hash (because the payment hash is itself the sha256() of the payment preimage).
        OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(payment_hash)> OP_EQUALVERIFY
        # Now the payment preimage is valid verify we've got a signature from both the local and the remote node to spend this coin.
        2 OP_SWAP <local_htlcpubkey> 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
    OP_ELSE
        # Otherwise, we assume this is the timeout path.
        # We must not be able to spend through this path before `cltv_expiry` blocks.
        OP_DROP <cltv_expiry> OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY OP_DROP
        # A signature against the remote HTLC pubkey is enough to spend after the timelock.
        OP_CHECKSIG
    OP_ENDIF
OP_ENDIF
```

*(I omitted `option_anchor_outputs` for simplicity and since it doesn't matter for this question.)*

If this output ends up onchain and we know the `sha256()` preimage of `payment_hash`, we can spend it using the corresponding HTLC-success transaction. We also cannot spend it another way, to make sure the revocation delay is enforced (see [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/97225/101498) and [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/95543/101498) answers for more about 2-stage HTLCs).

Here is the detailed script execution when spending using the HTLC-success transaction:

- Initial stack: `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig>  <payment_preimage>`
- Executing `OP_DUP`. Resulting stack: `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig>  <payment_preimage> <payment_preimage>`.
- Executing `OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(SHA256(revocationpubkey))> OP_EQUAL`. Resulting stack: `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig> <payment_preimage> 0`.
- Executing `OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(SHA256(revocationpubkey))> OP_EQUAL`. Resulting stack: `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig> <payment_preimage> 0`.
- Executing `OP_IF`, we "jump" in the `ELSE` branch of the conditional. Resulting stack: `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig> <payment_preimage>`.
- Executing `<remote_htlcpubkey> OP_SWAP`. Resulting stack: `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig> <remote_htlcpubkey> <payment_preimage>`.
- Executing `OP_SIZE 32 OP_EQUAL`. Resulting stack (since `payment_preimage` is 32 bytes long): `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig> <remote_htlcpubkey> <payment_preimage> 1`.
- Executing `OP_IF`, we "jump" in the first branch of the conditional. Resulting stack: `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig> <remote_htlcpubkey> <payment_preimage>`.
- Executing `OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(payment_hash)> OP_EQUALVERIFY`. Resulting stack: `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig> <remote_htlcpubkey>`.
- Executing `2 OP_SWAP <local_htlcpubkey> 2`. Resulting stack: `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig> 2 <remote_htlcpubkey> <local_htlcpubkey> 2`.
- Executing `OP_CHECKMULTISIG`. Resulting stack: `1`. (Do keep in mind the `CHECKMULTISIG` bug that makes it consume one-too-many elements on the stack.)

Comment: Thank you! I see. I had overlooked the fact that the second-stage HTLC success transactions are for "received HTLC outputs" while the second-stage HTLC timeout transactions are for "offered HTLC outputs".

Comment: You're welcome. I've added comments to the Script as well to (hopefully!) give more clarity about what it's doing.